# Why Spectral Method and GaussianMixture in FindClusters and ClusteringComponents can't set the number of Clusters?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

[image]

There is an official example, that we can set clusters number.

However, when I set the number to run the example, funny thing happens.

The same problem in `ClusteringComponents`

[image]

According to the theory of Spectral Clustering method, the feature number is the same to the eigenvectors sliced to use, which could be set by hand. Another reason is setting the number is the need for the final step of Spectral Clustering when using Kmeans method.

And this is also one feature of Spectral Clustering method.

So, what's the reasons for mathematica's strange behavior? Is it a bug？ I'm on Mac version of 13.1.

Meanwhile, in `GaussianMixture` method, we ca choose more components to clustering some data.

There is a same problem in `ClusteringComponents` method.

`FindClusters` introduced in Year 2007.
`ClusteringComponents` introduced in Year 2010.

Now is Year 2022, I think many people may try this method.

Comment: It does look like a bug or limitation of the spectral method. The "Spectral" method was not around in 2007 or 2010 though - according to the help page it was a new in version 12.